# VMWare Fusion > Full-Screen Displays > More than one & fewer than all. (n > x > 1, n=total x=desired)

Tags: macos, vmware, vmware-fusion

Just curious if anyone has figured out a way to force VMWare Fusion to use only a subset of the displays available when going Full-screen? (Available toggle is one or all)

I want to have one display show the Host PC (it's primary desktop), but I also need my VM to use more than one display. It's annoying to have to swipe to hide, or that it won't stay hidden when I give focus back to vmWare.

(crosspost: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190157/)